# Load settings from database in a config file

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using greggilbert/recaptcha and it uses config file config/recaptcha.php in which recaptcha keys need to be set:

```
'public_key'    => '',
'private_key'   => '',
```

How can I use some values from database for these keys?

When I try to use eloquent in the config file, I'm getting this error:

```
Call to a member function connection() on a non-object
```

Comment: Did you get what I'm trying to do? @Amit

Comment: @mpet, why you storing your keys in DB? Just copy them from DB and insert into config file.

Comment: @mpet, I'm using greggilbert/recaptcha too. I've put all my keys to custom config file, and retreive them from that.

Comment: You won't be able to use any code that involves facades or service providers in your config files, because those are loaded after that point. **And you shouldn't you do that in the first place**, config files are there to store config values and that's it. Please explain the reasoning behind not using the regular configuration described by the library, so we can maybe offer alternative solutions.